# Differentiate between two different click events on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to detect if a click event has been attached to an element, I can do the following:

```
function eventAlreadyBound($element){
    var boundEvents = $._data($element[0], 'events') || {};
    return boundEvents.hasOwnProperty('click');
}
```

If there's a click, returns true.

Now, say two different plugins want to add click one click event to the same element. If they both run the above check, then only the first plugin gets to apply its event.

How could plugin  B check to see if *its own* click has been applied while disregarding any click events applied by plugin A?

Can I name events? Attach ids to them? Something else?

Comment: You could check for `namespace`, so plugins should bound events with specific namespace: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/   But sounds like a XY problem, explain instead why would you need that behaviour? Regarding this: `How could plugin B check to see if its own click has been applied` then plugin should set entry in `data` object, and check there instead (or adding a specific class to element, or etc...)

Comment: You can detect the click and then `trigger` the click events of both plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach custom events in jQuery. 
They behave like normal events. 
Check out this guide - https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/